# Cannot update value in PHP

Tags: php, crud

I have a problem with updating value with PHP, it can get the data that I input but it cannot update it and render it to the read page.

```
<?php

require_once("session.php");
require_once("included_functions.php");
require_once("database.php");

new_header("VinceT");

$mysqli = Database::dbConnect();
$mysqli->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if (($output = message()) !== null) {
    echo $output;
}

echo "<h3>Update A Order</h3>";
echo "<div class='row'>";
echo "<label for='left-label' class='left inline'>";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE VTCustomer SET CustomerFName=? WHERE CustomerID=?");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST["CustomerFName"],$_POST["CustomerID"]]);

    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE VTCustomer SET CustomerLName=? WHERE CustomerID=?");
    $stmt1->execute([$_POST["CustomerLName"],$_POST["CustomerID"]]);
    
    if($stmt) {
        $_SESSION["message"] = $_POST["CustomerFName"]." has been updated";
    } else {
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Error! Could not update ".$_POST["CustomerFName"];
    }

    redirect("read.php");
} else {
    if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] !== "") {
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT OrderID FROM OrderVinceT WHERE OrderID=?");
        $stmt->execute([$_GET["id"]]);

        if ($stmt)  {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<h3>Order&nbsp;".$row["OrderID"]." Information</h3>";
            }

            echo "<form method='POST' action='update.php'>";
            echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'OrderID' value = ' ".$row['OrderID']." ' />";
            $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CustomerFName FROM VTCustomer WHERE CustomerID=?");
            $stmt1->execute([$_GET["id"]]);

            if ($stmt1)  {
                while ($row1 =$stmt1 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<p>Customer First Name: <input type='text' name='CustomerFName' value='".$row1["CustomerFName"]."'></p>";
                }
            }

            $stmt5 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CustomerLName FROM VTCustomer NATURAL JOIN OrderVinceT WHERE OrderVinceT.CustomerID=?");
            $stmt5->execute([$_GET["id"]]);

            if ($stmt5)  {
                while ($row5 =$stmt5 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<p>Customer Last Name: <input type='text' name='CustomerLName' value='".$row5["CustomerLName"]."'></p>";
                }
            }

            echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update Order' class='tiny round button'/>";
            echo "</form>";

            echo "<br /><p>&laquo:<a href='read.php'>Back to Main Page</a>";
            echo "</label>";
            echo "</div>";
        } else {
            $_SESSION["message"] = "Order could not be found!";
            redirect("read.php");
        }
    }
}

new_footer("VinceT");
Database::dbDisconnect($mysqli);
?>
```

Do you guys have any idia why I cannot update this? I test queries in the console and it works just fine. The if statement that render out the message still receive the value of the input but it cannot update the database that render out in read.php

Comment: Can your write the error?

Comment: it does not show up any error, after I hit submit button still redirect to read page with the value that I update but the read table does not update.

Comment: Here is the link so you can try it: https://turing.cs.olemiss.edu/~ttcao/FinalProject/read.php

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); <- use this at line 1

Comment: after i use that my db doesn't display anymore